# Does "new city" mean a city no other players are infecting?

Tags: pandemic-contagion

There is an Event Card which has the text:

> **Massive Bird Migration**
>
> You may move 1 of your disease cubes from a city you are currently infecting to a new city.

Does *new city* here mean a city which isn't already infected by another player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new city means one that you are currently not infecting.

From the infect a city infection [rules](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Pandemic_Contagion.pdf),

> You can infect a new city OR a city you are currently infecting.
>
> new city: Discard 2 cards whose color must match the city you
>   wish to infect. Place your disease cube(s) on the uppermost
>   available row (without any cubes).
>
> City you are currently infecting: Discard 1 card whose color must
>   match the city you are currently infecting. Place your disease
>   cube(s) next to those already on the City card.

Comment: I concur. New city means new to you.